# Creating Cognito Identity Pool Programmatically - AccessDeniedException

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js

I am trying to create an identity pool using the aws-sdk for javascript. Here is my code for creating the pool:

```
const defaultCognitoIdentityPoolConfig = {
  AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities: true,
};

const createUserIDPoolConfig = (defaultConfig, poolName, userPoolId, appClientId) => {
  return {
    IdentityPoolName: poolName,
    CognitoIdentityProviders: [
      {
        ClientId: appClientId,
        ProviderName: `cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/${userPoolId}`,
        ServerSideTokenCheck: true,
      },
    ],
    SupportedLoginProviders: {
      [`cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/${userPoolId}`]: appClientId,
    },
    ...defaultConfig,
  };
};

const getCognitoIDClient = async () => {
  const credentials = Auth.essentialCredentials(await Auth.currentCredentials());
  return new AWS.CognitoIdentity({
    apiVersion: '2014-06-30',
    accessKeyId: credentials.accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: credentials.secretAccessKey,
    sessionToken: credentials.sessionToken,
    region: 'us-west-2',
    sslEnabled: true,
  });
};

const cognitoIDClient = await getCognitoIDClient();
const createIDPoolResult = await cognitoIDClient.createIdentityPool(createUserIDPoolConfig(defaultCognitoIdentityPoolConfig,`POOL_NAME`,createUserPoolResult.UserPool.Id,createAppClientResult.UserPoolClient.ClientId)).promise();
```

I am trying to create this pool logged in as an authenticated user. Authenticated by a Cognito user pool and authorized by an identity pool role. Here is the IAM policy that is attached to the logged in user:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-identity:*",
                "cognito-idp:CreateUserPoolClient",
                "cognito-idp:CreateUserPool"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am getting: AccessDeniedException: These credentials are not valid for accessing this resource.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcjrY.png)

I have also tried using the credentials attribute when creating the cognito identity client object but got the same error.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?